# What is the email for the Jettison mailing list?

Tags: jettison

Sounds like a stupid question, doesn't it?

But the page on the [Jettison project](http://jettison.codehaus.org/Mailing+Lists) mentions the [Codehaus mailing subscription page](http://xircles.codehaus.org/manage_email/manage), which in turn asks for the mailing list name before you can subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://xircles.codehaus.org/projects/jettison/lists